# Using Node with a Spring backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, spring, npm

I'm working on a project with React as frontend and Spring as backend (I'm running both on the same machine).

Since I'm using a Spring backend, which doesn't rely on Node, and I'm using the browser to display the frontend created by React, can I uninstall node.js from my computer? Can everything work right if I don't even have node on my machine? In that case, how to run my React project?

I mean why should I have a folder node_modules in my React projects when I don't see any usage of Node in my situation (except the usage of NPM)?

Comment: Keep node js installed since you will be using React and you may need to install more dependencies using `npm` which requires node js.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll at least need node installed for babel/webpack, to transpile/bundle your jsx.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use Node as back end service, then the only usage of node here is, for node module management and you don't require node installed in your server. So build your front end react application and place all the web resources(bundle.js, index.htm ,... etc) inside the spring resource folder
([ref](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)).